# natbib: supressing first name abbreviations in text

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I cite two authors with the same last name. When citing them in the document, `natbib` automatically adds the first names (abbreviated), to differentiate between them. I saw that with `biblatex`, one can add `[uniquename=false]`, to suppress such a thing happening. I have not found a similar option in `natbib`. Is it possible to suppress it in `natbib` in some way though?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

... \citet{jones1991} ... \citet{jonesetal2008}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{testxyz}

\end{document}
```

The respective `.bib` file is as follows:

```
@article{jones1991,
author = {Jones, Jennifer J.},
journal = {Journal of Accounting Research},
number = {2},
pages = {193--228},
publisher = {[Accounting Research Center, Booth School of Business, University of Chicago, Wiley]},
title = {Earnings Management During Import Relief Investigations},
volume = {29},
year = {1991}
}

@article{jonesetal2008,
author = {Jones, Keith L. and Krishnan, Gopal V. and Melendrez, Kevin D.},
     title = {Do Models of Discretionary Accruals Detect Actual Cases of Fraudulent and Restated    Earnings? An        Empirical Analysis},
 journal = {Contemporary Accounting Research},
 volume = {25},
 number = {2},
 pages = {499-531},
 year = {2008}
 }
```

Comment: Your claim that "`natbib` automatically adds the first names (abbreviatied), to differentiate between them" and all further references to `natbib` are incorrect. It is *not* the `natbib` package which performs this disambiguation. Instead, it's the `apacite` package, which implements the formatting guidelines of the 6th edition of the APA manual. (By the way, the same disambiguation rule applies for the 7th edition.) In my view, the only valid reason for using the `apacite` citation management package and associated bib style is that you're *required* to do so. If it's not, don't use 'em.

Comment: Under *absolutely no circumstance* should you be loading both the `apacite` package and the `natbib` package. If you wish to use the macro names `\citet` and `\citep` while using the `apacite` package and associated bibliography style, you should run `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` -- and delete the `\usepackage{natbib}` instruction.

Comment: In short, if you want to suppress the disambiguation rule while otherwise following the formatting guidelines of the APA manual, you should *not* employ the `apacite` package and BibTeX; instead, you should employ `biblatex` -- with options `style=apa` (or `style=apa6`, if you prefer) and `uniquename=false` -- and biber.

Comment: The disambiguation initial is added because you are using `apacite`, which implements (6th ed.) APA style, where addition of the initial is required in this case (https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/01/when-to-use-author-initials-for-text-citations.html). If you don't want that, it may be better not to use `apacite` at all. (In any case, while `apacite` and `natbib` *can* be combined if so desired, you need to go about this slightly differently than you do at the moment. See the `apacite` documentation and search for `natbibapa`.)